# Installing spacepy, cdf and pycdf on macbook

Tags: python

Tried to download spacepy using pip install spacepy, tried to upgrade pip to install, python and anaconda newest version also installed not working, comes this error code:

> ERROR: Could not build wheels for spacepy, which is required to
> install pyproject.toml-based projects

Any help would be appreciated, it seems any solution I've found doesn't work for a macbook pro.

Comment: if you have anaconda installed, did you try installing via `conda`?

Comment: I did, it didn't work, not sure where I am going wrong.